# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I created a function that returns Promise

```
ject 

i can access the response's data inside the scoop of the 'then' accessor and read it's value there, but outside the data is not being attributed to the 'User' object so it's returning this error : 
>Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Comment: where is this.user defined and where the associated class?

Comment: please check the answer i updated it with the declaration of user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your console.log is out of then function.

Because the function then wait for the response, when you put out of the function, Angular will continue the process

If you want to access this form, you can write the code like this:

```js
async ngOnInit(){
  try{
    const value =    await this.userService.getCurrentUser()
    this.user.firstName = value['data']['first_name'];
    console.log(this.user.firstName);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me , i accepted your answer